# Redirect to another page after countdown

Tags: javascript

I have this bit of code, I would like the user to be redirected to another page (test.html) after a 10 second timer has gone by. How would I accomplish this if the "if" statement is true.

```js
case 'disconnect':
  if (connect === 1) {
    $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Disconnecting...<br>Disconnected<br><br><span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
    disconnect = 1;
    connect = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
  } else {
    $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Failed.<span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
  }
  break;
default:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){

  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    window.location='http://www.google.com';
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method.

ex.

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href="YOUR ADDRESS HERE";
},10000);
```

This would redirect the page after a time of 10000ms (10 seconds) has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope adding this works for you.

```
var seconds = 10;
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '/test.html'; }, seconds*1000);
```

```js
case 'disconnect':
  if (connect === 1) {
    $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Disconnecting...<br>Disconnected<br><br><span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
    disconnect = 1;
    connect = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 10;
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '/test.html'; }, seconds*1000);

  } else {
    $('#terminal').append('<div>C:/root/anon> ' + $(this).val() + '<br><br>Failed.<span id="blinking">_</span></div>');
  }
  break;
default:
```